# Growth rate of arithmetical function

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

I'm interested in how one would estimate the growth rate of

$$f(n)=\sum_{k\le n}\mu^2(k)\log(k)$$

I.e. sum of logarithms of square free integers. I can think of some trivial methods in my head (like using the fact that the density of the sqrfree integers is $6/\pi^2$) but perhaps there's a smarter way. If there was a way of truncating

$$h(s)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu^2(k)\log(k)}{k^s}$$
We could use that, and I think I have seen something of this nature before, that is, truncating Dirichlet series. But anyway, what is your approach?

Comment: Have you tried $\sum_{k\leq n} \log k - \sum_{k^2 \leq n, j\leq n/k^2}(1-\mu^2(jk^2))\log{jk^2}$.  There's some double-counting to overcome, but neither of the sums nested on the right are particularly difficult to estimate.

Comment: Since the square-free integers are rather well-distributed among the integers and the $\log(x)$  function has a small derivative, I am expecting that $$\sum_{k\leq n}\mu^2(k)\log k = \frac{6}{\pi^2}n\log n+O(n)$$ follows by partial summation. How sharp you need the remainder to be?

Comment: not too sharp it seems, and yeah I just looked up the Abel summation formula and this seems to be right :)